# Интерпретатор и $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php

Приветствую, я в панике бегаю уже вокруг города. Проблема в том что если запускать крон через интерпретатор php то $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] просто пуст. А он мне очень нужен, как быть подскажите.

Comment: Если вы знаете, где относительно корня находится файл, то корень легко находится через dirname(__FILE__) и соответвующие переход вверх или вниз по папкам в зависимости от расположения запускаемого файла.

Comment: а кроме этого варианта нет не чего? Просто всегда использовал что то такое:
$r=dirname(__FILE__);
$r= substr($r,0, -4);
Но мне кажется что это не нормально.

Comment: @wwwplaton, через substr что-то делать - да, ненормально. Есть basename, который сократит путь на одну директорию, есть псевдодиректория .., которая обозначает родительскую директорию.

Comment: Но ведь всегда есть самый простой способ, что называется в лоб:

    if(empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "Путь, который я думаю вам известен, а если и не известен, то вы его легко можете определить"

Comment: @MDJHD, я бы пошел от обратного и задавал наоборот вызовонезависимый APP_ROOT ) но это кому как удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` устанавливается веб-сервером. При command-line запуске PHP из крона, разумеется, это значение отсутствует. Поэтому нужно самостоятельно его присвоить.

а) если оно не меняется и вы его можете жестко прописать, то например, так:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?: '/var/www/my_project';
```

b) если исполняемый файл находится в корне сайта

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?: dirname(__FILE__);
```

c) если корень сайта на два уровня выше исполняемого файла:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?: dirname( dirname( (dirname(__FILE__))));
```

Comment: А если это значение меняется, то что в первый раз принял а после добавления нового задания опять появилась внутреняя ошибка сервера. То что прописать в таком случае или как прописать?

Comment: я бы дополнил, что нужно использовать `Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory`, например. Чтобы можно было иметь возможность самому заполнять массивы.